# Playing CDN Soundfonts on Mobile Devices

Tags: javascript, laravel, soundfont

I have developed my first ever Laravel web application, which you can find at: [www.sharpguitartraining.com](https://www.sharpguitartraining.com/identifynote/show/1), and that uses .mp3 files from [gleitz/midi-js-soundfonts](https://github.com/gleitz/midi-js-soundfonts) CDN to play guitar notes one at a time, and it works fine on desktop computers, but is totally silent in both iOS and Android devices.

This is how I play the sounds on the website:

```
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mudcube/MIDI.js/a8a84257/inc/shim/Base64.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mudcube/MIDI.js/a8a84257/inc/shim/Base64binary.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mudcube/MIDI.js/a8a84257/inc/shim/WebAudioAPI.js"></script>
    <!-- midi.js package -->
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mudcube/MIDI.js/a8a84257/js/midi/audioDetect.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mudcube/MIDI.js/a8a84257/js/midi/gm.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mudcube/MIDI.js/a8a84257/js/midi/loader.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mudcube/MIDI.js/a8a84257/js/midi/plugin.audiotag.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mudcube/MIDI.js/a8a84257/js/midi/plugin.webaudio.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mudcube/MIDI.js/a8a84257/js/midi/plugin.webmidi.js"></script>
    <!-- utils -->
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mudcube/MIDI.js/a8a84257/js/util/dom_request_xhr.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mudcube/MIDI.js/a8a84257/js/util/dom_request_script.js"></script>

function playNote_CDN(note, sonido_id, velocity, delay, mensaje) {
        var instrument_name = sonido_id ? $('#sonidos')[0].options[sonido_id].text : $('#sonidos')[0].selectedOptions[0].text;
        var delay = delay ? delay : 0; // play one note every quarter second
        var velocity = velocity ? velocity : 127; // how hard the note hits
        var note = note ? note - 1 : 61;
        var volumen = $('#volumen').val() / 100 * 127;
            MIDI.loadPlugin({
                soundfontUrl: "http://gleitz.github.io/midi-js-soundfonts/FluidR3_GM/",
                instrument: instrument_name,
                onprogress: function(state, progress) {
                },
                onsuccess: function () {
                    if (mensaje) {
                        muestraMensaje("Instrumento " + instrument_name + " cargado.", 3);
                    }
                    MIDI.programChange(0, MIDI.GM.byName[instrument_name].number);
                    MIDI.setVolume(0, volumen);
                    MIDI.noteOn(0, note, velocity, delay);
                    MIDI.noteOff(0, note, delay + 1);
                }
            }); 
    }
```

I have no clue how to proceed, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I didn´t get an answer, but I figured out the issue. I was calling gleitz/midi-js-soundfonts, whose CDN is in a http:// protocol from my site which is in a https:// protocol so Chrome was blocking the call, for apparently you are not allowed to call an unsecured http CDN from a secure https site. This is preety explicit on Chrome's dev console.
Hope this helps someone else.
Cheers!